# Create module with components AND services

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular-components, angular5

I am currently developing an Ionic 3 application. In this context, I needed an accordion component like the one of [NgBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) but the Ionic framework does not provide such a component. So I decided to implement one myself, what is a good opportunity to me to continue to learn Angular 5.

To clarify the context of my question, you need to know that my component is defined through this file tree:

```
components/
   my-accordion/
      my-accordion.component.html
      my-accordion.component.css
      my-accordion.component.ts
      my-accordion.service.ts
```

Actually, I need a specific service to allow communication between all instances of my components. Because when I open one of the item of my accordion, I want the other to be closed automatically to have only one opened item at a time. I don't know if it is the right way to do it but it seems to work well with the RxJS library.

Anyway, as you can see, the definition of my accordion depends on a Component AND a Service. Without the service, my accordion cannot works well. The thing is I would like to put it in a module that I could share with other application to be able to reuse my accordion.

The first idea I had was to put it in the `SharedModule`, but the [ngModules FAQs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-kinds-of-ngmodules-should-i-have-and-how-should-i-use-them) explicitely says that:

> The SharedModule should not have providers for reasons explained
>   previously. Nor should any of its imported or re-exported NgModules
>   have providers.

After reading that, my second thought was to put my accordion in the `CoreModule`, but again the doc explicitely said that:

> Consider making CoreModule a pure services module with no
>   declarations.

Hence my question: Where to put a component AND it service (for sibling communication) if I want to be able to reuse it in other Ionic/Angular application ?

Comment: I think in this case you should not use a service. Just do the job with javascript in your component.

Comment: Actually, I managed to implement the communication between the items of the accordion simply by using `@Input` annotation and without any service. But according to what I read on the official doc of Angular, the right way would be to create a `Feature module` and  to use a static method which would define the module and the providers it exports to avoid any issue when the module is lazy loaded.

Comment: The following article well describe how to implement such a `Feature module`: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-invent the wheel. There is an Ionic `accordion` component where you can use with `Ionic 3` app.

Here it is [**Ionic Accordion**](https://github.com/mahmoudissmail/ionic2Accordion)

**Q:**

> Where to put a component AND it service (for sibling communication) if
>   I want to be able to reuse it in other Ionic/Angular application?

**A:**

It has a very simple answer with `Ionic`. You just need to create a `provider` using this `CLI` `ionic generate provider MyAccordion`. That is it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Indeed I only searched on the Ionic official components list and there was not any `accordion` component. But to get back to my original question, where should I put such a component working with a service for sibling communication? Is there any guideline to create a module with both components AND services?

Comment: Please see the Update.

Comment: A `provider` is just a mecanism to inject a service as a singleton isn't it?

Comment: Yes, It is. Normally we declare it inside the `app.module.ts` file.